# How to check if the route child is exist - Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to redirect User if he move to the wrong child route. I have created the guard for a child component which is requesting to the api for the data, but i am not sure how can i redirect user if the data does not exist. I would like to display 404 for the user if the data does not exist or redirect to the main page. Sorry if duplicated, but i could not find solution for it.

Scenario:

1. User have to pass the password to redirect to his movies. (Auth.Service)

```
 public login(password: string) {
    firebase.database().ref("clients")
      .orderByChild("password").equalTo(password).once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const route = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
          this.router.navigate(["/strefa-klienta", route]);
        } else {
          this._snackBar.open(
            "Podano błędne hasło. Spróbuj jeszcze raz.",
            "Zamknij",
            { duration: 2000 }
          );
        }
      });
  }
```

2. If passed the User is redirect to his route page and the guard request for the data (guard)

```
canActivate(
    child: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.clientsState.loading$.pipe(
      map(loading => {
        if (!loading) {
          this.clientsState.load(child.url[0].path);
        }
        return true;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

This is my app-routing.module

```
{
   path: "strefa-klienta",
   children: [
     {
       path: "",
       pathMatch: "full",
       redirectTo: "/"
     },
     {
       path: ":id",
       component: components.ClientSiteComponent,
       canActivate: [guards.ClientGuard]
     },
   ],
}
```

For example. I have 2 users [ John, Rick ] ("/strefa-klienta/John"). If someone will try to find a user which does not exist "Anna" ("/strefa-klienta/Anna") I would like to show 404.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add this in your app-routing.module

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Comment: I have tried it before but it was not change anything. In the path i can write the random parameter and it will still routing. (/strefa-klienta/example_text).